# Android Room automatic-migrations?

Tags: android, database-migration, android-room, automatic-migration

Is there a way of doing an automatic migration when needed with Room Persistance library in Android? Like Django migrations where you just execute `makemigrations` and `migrate` and it migrates automatically. It also increments the database version. And if there is a migration it cannot do, it tells/suggest you how to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Room automatically runs migrations; there is no manual option to do so, outside of running tests. Room uses the standard `SQLiteOpenHelper` engine for this, and so it handles schema version tracking automatically as well.

Room does not automatically *create* `Migration` classes with the migration code; you must write those yourself.

Comment: What a pitty... I hope this feature will be added in the future to have it as simple as in Django.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at this in 2021, android room implementation of anything higher than 2.4.0-alpha01 now supports auto migrations. More information here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions